# Perl, is this tcp socket a server or client socket?

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp

I want write this in a android app and I need to know which kind of Java socket I should use "Client" or Server".
If someone could say more about this code it would be very helpfull for me.
As far as I understand. The Code creates a Client Socket to the IP "$cleintIP" and waits for a message.

```
if (&  eq "OK") {
  print "\nEnabling Shoot&View Mode\n";
  my $ShootAndView = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto=>"tcp",PeerPort=>5566,PeerAddr=>$CardIP) 
    or die "Can't make TCP socket: $@";

  my ($datagram1,$flags1);

  until(1!=1) {  
    eval {
      local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
      alarm 5; # Set Timer to check if card is still alive every XX seconds by TCP ECHO (not ICMP!)

      $ShootAndView->recv($datagram1,250,$flags1);
      alarm 0; # if we get a info about new files we disable the alarm here
    };

    if ($@) {
      die unless $@ eq "alarm\n"; #if we got the alarmtime we have to check if card is alive

      #if card is unreachable we have to find it again!
      if (&KeepCardAlive eq "NOK") { 
        print "\nClosing Shoot And View...\n";
        close($ShootAndView);
        print "Back to start...\n";
        goto START;
        };
      }
    else {
      print "\nThere's something new on ", $ShootAndView->peerhost,": $datagram1\n"; 
      #And now for some regex! --> Remove >/mnt from >/mnt/sd/DCIM/200MSDCF/_DSC3233.JPG
      $datagram1 =~ s/^>\/mnt//;

      #system('wget http://admin:admin@192.168.11.254/sd/DCIM/200MSDCF/_DSC3233.JPG');     
      my $wget = join("","wget -bqc http://",$User,":",$Password,"@",$CardIP,$datagram1,);
      system($wget); 
    };
  };
}
else {
  print "\nNothing found. Waiting 10 Seconds...\n";
  sleep(10);
  goto START;
};
```

Comment: that is...some truly badly written perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code connects to an ip address, instead of passively waiting for a connection. This means it uses a "client socket."

Answer (score 1):

A server socket is one that's passed to `accept` instead of `connect`. Data is neither sent nor received on a server socket; it's merely used to listen for connection.

IO::Socket::INET calls `connect` when there's a `PeerAddr` or `PeerHost` parameter. There is a PeerAddr parameter, so it's a client socket.